# Show camera shutter programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In order to make my custom `UIImagePickerSourceTypeCamera`, I had to do this:

```
pickerOne = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerOne.delegate = self;
pickerOne.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
pickerOne.showsCameraControls = NO;
pickerOne.navigationBarHidden = YES;
pickerOne.toolbarHidden = YES;
pickerOne.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

But now, when I take a picture like this:

```
[cameraButton addTarget:pickerOne 
                 action:@selector(takePicture)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

it doesn't show the shutter when you take the picture. Is there a way to show it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. The trick is to do the following:

Enable the camera controls on initializing the picker (this will enable the shutter view).

```
pickerOne.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

Overlay the camera controls with your own view which has the `cameraButton`

In your `takePicture:` method do the following:

```
pickerOne.showsCameraControls = NO;
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.0]];
[pickerOne takePicture];
```

In the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method do the following:

```
pickerOne.showsCameraControls = YES;  // perform on main thread
```

Comment: Ok! I'll try it out.. But I didn't think you could overlay a UIView with `showCameraControls` on? If you can how?

Comment: This should work. I am doing this in CameraLevel You can use a UIToolbar e.g:  `UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 480.0-56.0, 320.0, 56.0)]; <toolbar init...> [pickerOne addSubview:toolbar];`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to control the "shutter" affect. You can however create your own image and add the affect in there.

Comment: That's what I thought... How would I "create my own image and add that affect" in there? Can you please explain a little better? Thanks.

Comment: You could possibly add a `UIImage` subview when you take your photo.